# How to set default null value in to a date field in sql server 2000?

Tags: sql-server-2000

How to set deafult null value in to a date field in the table,if the parameter containing the date value is null?

Comment: you are asking how to  set null when inserting a null date field ?

Comment: yes.if the date parameter is null then the dafault value will be '01/01/1900'.I want this to be NULL

Comment: What's the table definition? And how is the data getting to SQL Server? If 'NULL' is passed in with an INSERT or UPDATE, then a NULL will gets saved. If this is being translated to a date, then it's either a table definition issue (DEFAULT constraint or trigger) or the code that's doing the insert/update is translating NULL to a date.

Comment: @Adarsh, see my answer, null is null and not a particular date...

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are really passing in NULL, I think you are passing in an empty string.  If you pass in empty string, you get the `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000` value that you refer to.  Null will be null and not change to a date.

try this test code:

```
declare @x datetime

select 'is null', @x

set @x=''

select 'is empty string', @x
```

OUTPUT:

```
------- -----------------------
is null NULL

(1 row(s) affected)


--------------- -----------------------
is empty string 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean how do you set a specific default value in a stored procedure when the date parameter passed in is NULL?

Mark your date parameter like this:

@DOB DATETIME = '01/01/1900'

And the @DOB parameter would then insert '01/01/1900' if @DOB is passed as NULL.

Comment: if the date parameter is null then the dafault value will be '01/01/1900'.I want this to be NULL

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
coalesce(param, getdate())
```

in your stored procedure or define a default value on your column

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Mitarbeiter ADD CONSTRAINT
DF_Mitarbeiter_Geburtstag DEFAULT getdate() FOR Geburtstag
```

Comment: if the date parameter is null then the dafault value will be '01/01/1900'.I want this to be NULL

Comment: Ahhh - sorry, got confused. Pls. post your table create statement.

Answer (score 0):

I am not expert on sql server 2000.

i got one link hope this will help you :)

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sd_patel/EnterNullValuesForDateTime11222005015742AM/EnterNullValuesForDateTime.aspx